# Quick release skewer installation help

Tags: road-bike, bso

I was wondering if I could easily install a quick release skewer on my Kent 700c Mens roadtech bike that I got from Walmart. If not what would i need to do in order to do so.

Comment: The work to do this would probably cost a good portion of the bike itself. Theres a product called Axle Release which you can install pretty quickly yourself though, which does quick release-like functionality.

Comment: Also remember QRs are somewhat less secure when locked in a rack because there's no-tool removal compared to an axle with nuts.

Comment: Also consider that money spent on a wallyworld bike is money you're not saving for a nice bike.

Comment: Follow the link to the answer Batman provided at the top here. It goes into more detail about the issues you will face if you decide to swap out the axles to use a quick release. (width of frame etc)

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is *'no'*, you cannot "easily install a quick release skewer" on this bike.

The easiest way would be to buy a different front wheel that is already built with a QR skewer and swap the whole wheel out (make sure to check for correct size and hub spacing before you purchase). Alternatively, you could buy just a new hub that uses a QR skewer, but to swap-out your hubs you'd essentially be re-building your wheel (spoke by spoke) which requires a lot of expertise and specialized tools.

As an alternative, you might consider finding some vintage winged-nuts. If you can find some that fit your current axles, they will serve the same/similar function as a quick-release skewer (that is, they'd allow you to quickly remove your front wheel without the use of a tool).
[image]

Comment: Assuming you can find the right hollow axle to fit the existing hub, replacing just the axle of a standard design hub would be MUCH MUCH easier than replacing the hub.  With the right part a front axle can be replaced in about 5 minutes.  A rear axle would take 10-20, as you have to first get the cluster out of the way.  Of course there are fancy hubs that require a post-doc course to deal with, but they're likely already QR.